# CSS transform showing background color in border

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have two `<div>` elements. When the user hovers, a transformation of `transform: translateY(x, y);` is applied. However, a black border also somehow appears (there should only be a red border) when the user hovers.

**Resolution:** 1920*1080
[image]

```css
.link {
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.element {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.link:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <div class="element">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not show any issue. If you are trying to remove the border, then just remove the border on hover `border:none;`

Comment: sorry missed add info am facing issue in 1920X resolution.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I have tried to help you with your grammar with an edit. Could you review the edit and make sure that it matches your logic?

Comment: Could you elaborate on 1920x resolution? Do you mean 1920x1080 resolutions? Is 1920 the pixel width or height of the screen?

Comment: updated resolution 1920*1080

Comment: I don't see a black border anywhere on hover.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot.

Comment: @TAMILARASU yes i did see that black border but only on the top and the bottom of the box, Idk why.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure I am understanding the problem, but one way to get rid of the black on hover is to set the background to transparent then. See snippet below.

Note that trying to get exact alignment of very thin borders/lines (1 CSSpx in this case) is not always possible given modern displays use several 'physical' pixels for one CSS pixel. Sometimes zooming in/out shows/doesn't show 1 (display) pixel 'left behind'. And I have seen this in this case, so certain display sizes may show the black.

```css
.link {
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.element {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.link:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <div class="element">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```